# Bootstrap responsive container (like columns)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

This might be a bit of a silly question - but I could not find an answer to what I'm trying to do..

I'm trying to make the entire container div responsive (like a column inside a row).

e.g. I want to have the effect that this would produce:

```
<div className="container">
   <div className="row justify-content-center">
      <div className="col-lg-6 cold-sm-10">
         ...
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

but in one line... something like:

```
<div className="container-lg-6 container-sm-10">
   ...
</div>
```

Is there something in Bootstrap that could achieve this?

I tried the classes `container-sm` but they are not working like what I want.

Answer (score 1):

That is not how the containers work. But you can easily achieve the layout by just nesting everything inside of a `.col-12.col-sm-10.col-lg-6` inside a `.row` inside a `.container-fluid`

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 col-lg-6">


      <div class="row">
        <div class="col bg-primary">
          <h1>1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col bg-secondary">
          <h1>2</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col bg-info">
          <h1>3</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col bg-info">
          <h1>4</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col bg-primary">
          <h1>5</h1>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```